# Overlaying a transparent image over a video in C#

Tags: c#, image, video, overlay

I am currently making a skydive simulator in C# for a project. I have worked out all the code for a basic simulator with all the forces worked out. But to improve the aesthetics of my program I would like to have an image of a skydiver overplayed a video of some sky with moving clouds and simulated wind lines. All the video and image would be easy to create but I'm just wondering if it is possible to overlay a transparent image over a video. Any tips would be greatly appreciated and if anyone has any other ways of producing this effect I would love to hear them as I am completely stuck on this final piece of my project.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Jon Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.

Comment: Please show us your code and maybe a jsfiddle so we can help improve it